# Solar cell failure

Tags: current, motor, solar-cell

I am a student in high school, and I am working on a project. I got a Solarbotics Marble Machine, and I could not get the solar cell to transfer power to the motor. I talked to my Robotics teacher and we could not figure out the problem, however, we figured that it had something to do with current. The solar cell was giving out more than enough voltage to supply the board, (5.0 V), and we tested out motor, and it would run all the way down to 0.4 V. When we tested current however, the solar cell (in direct sunlight) was sending 5 mA to the motor.

Here is the link to the manual, if it helps:  https://cdn.solarbotics.com/products/documentation/marble%20doc%20greyscale2.pdf [back of board[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uiVp.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uiVp.jpg)[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Have you tried contacting Solarbotics support directly? They may have good troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Why not test the panel against a known load such as a resistor and see what its power curve is like. Also power the motor to find out how it behaves - there must be something amiss.

Comment: That tiny solar cell might turn on a few LEDs with resistors but never a motor .  Spec looks like 50~80 mW and DC motors draw 10x rated power to start if at rated voltage

Comment: At best this puny solar cell can charge up a battery all day to run the motor for a few minutes

Comment: How bright is your light source?  For this type of troubleshooting you should use bright sunlight perpendicular to the panel.  Will the motor run with no load?  If it will, have you removed all possible sources of friction?  It's a kit from a reputable company and I have a panel about 3x the size that can run a CD ROM tray motor quite vigorously in bright sunlight, so it could be that they cut things a little close in terms of the strength of the motor.  At any rate, you can take the kit apart, smooth every part that must move against another part.

Comment: Especially check any bearings for friction(like a rod going through a hole if there are no ball bearings present) and ensure when you're putting it back together that there is no undue friction caused by bending or pinching.  Things should be assembled firmly, mechanically secure, but not deathgripped together.

Comment: @SolarMike we did. Everything seemed to be working fine, including the solar cell and motor.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist we actually gauged the voltage coming from the cell and applied it (from another source) and it worked fine! Hmmmm...

Comment: @KH we are sure that it’s not the friction. We used alternates for many things and it worked fine.

Comment: So what is the problem? Pv current or motor current? Or non issue?

Comment: @JacksonSandstrum be sure to check your solar panel for micro cracks or signs of stress.  Unless the panel has built in current limiting, if you attach a load that overdraws it, voltage will drop as current increases, so it's not a question of what the voltage of the panel is with no load (open circuit voltage) but what the voltage will be at a certain load.  This is why solar mike is recommending you test with a certain load.  You can take a variety of resistors, attach them to the panel and measure the voltage across the resistor.

Comment: As you get to smaller resistors and output current increases you will see the point where voltage drops off too much for the increase in current to be worthwhile, called the maximum power point.  If you don't have current regulation on your panel and the panel's output is too low, its output voltage can drop too much to be useful.  How bright is your light source?  Spectrum matters.

Comment: Also are you using the bare panel to power the motor or have you given it a nice big capacitor to charge up between turnings?  Is the capacitor OK?

Comment: I uploaded some puctures. If you need more, just ask

Answer (score 0):

I really wish they'd included a schematic of the circuit in the manual. Can you take a good color picture of the non-component side of the circuit board and edit it into you question? The picture in the manual is (deliberately?) too low-contrast to see anything. I've figured out that the "trigger" is a Microchip [MCP112 supervisory chip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001889F.pdf), but I can't quite get how they're driving the transistor.

Here's the best I can get from staring at the photos:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN7iou.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ah! Found a description of it [here](http://solarbotics.net/library/circuits/se_t1_mse.html). Except that in this version, they forgot to put the current-limiting resistor between the trigger and the transistor, which is abuse of both of these components. One or the other may have failed as a result.

After replacing whichever has failed, I would recommend cutting the trace that runs between these two components and bridging a 1k resistor across the gap.